# Overlay Two Grey Images in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am having too much difficulty with this task... I have two grey images, I want to convert one of them to some other color intensity (idk green for example), and combine it with the original scheme. Something like this....

[image]

Assume I have two files :

```
img_avg = cv2.imread(directory + "/xzIMatrixaveraged/1.png")
img_dyn = cv2.imread(directory + "/xzIMatrixdynamic/1.png")
```

How would I easiest accomplish this in python?

Comment: What have you tried?  You know you can get your gray scale image as a numpy array. From there, it's just some matrix manipulation to convert `[g]` into `[0,g,0]`.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand - please try to improve it. If you have 2 input images and a result image, please show all three.

Answer (score 1):

I can guide you through with the help of the OpenCV Library,

Here's a detailed Notebook in Google Colab I have prepared for you to check out and solve your query.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13Ss39EbMOts1SLcU9fGBfu7f_jS7qFx0?authuser=1

The summary being:

```
def mask_color_img(img, mask, color=[0, 255, 255], alpha=0.3):
    '''
    img: cv2 image
    mask: bool or np.where
    color: BGR triplet [_, _, _]. Default: [0, 255, 255] is yellow.
    alpha: float [0, 1]. 

Ref: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/07/transparent-overlays-with-opencv/
'''
out = img.copy()
img_layer = img.copy()
img_layer[mask] = color
out = cv2.addWeighted(img_layer, alpha, out, 1 - alpha, 0, out)
return(out)
```

Comment: Your link provides a Notebook loading error ... do you mind changing the needed credentials